# Nuclear launch details

Tags: starcraft-2

1. Must a ghost see a location to which it plans to throw a bomb?
2. If "yes", is it required to see that target location the WHOLE time or it is enough to see it for launch only?
3. Can Ghost switch-on cloaking after launch is started before launch is completed?
4. How much damage does a nuclear missile do? I see it depends on the distance from the exposure center to the target. But what is a dependency? A supply depot close to center will be destroyed, so the damage is at least 400 HP... but what is exact value?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No
3. No (at least not till 2 seconds before the nuke lands)
4. 300 (+200 vs. structures) damage in a large radius (though in the single player tosh does 700 + 500 vs structures

Answer (score 20):

A nuke does 500 to buildings, 300 to units in the center. It decays as you go outward, as shown in this image from the Liquidpedia entry on [Nukes](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Nuke).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes.

2) It needs to see the location as long as the reticule is there.  As soon as the moving part reaches the center, he can move.

3) No.

4) Not sure.